# Am trying to send email via codeigniter's email library. And am getting some error after it working like 2 times

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to send email via codeigniter's email library.
And am getting some error after it working like 2 times.
Error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2063

Email function:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'email@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'emailpassword';
            $config['validate'] = FALSE;
            $config['priority'] = 3;
            $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
            $config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
            $config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
```

Most people are saying they had antivirus using this port unfortunately i don't have any antivirus appart from windows 10 defender..

Comment: I'd check if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570064/gmail-fsockopen-ssl-operation-failed-error-with-codeigniter-and-xampp